# Circleci locally throwing Error response from daemon: invalid UTS mode on multiple continers

Tags: docker, circleci

I am trying to get circleci to run locally to understand why test cases are failing but I keep running into the following error

`Error starting container <container>: Error response from daemon: invalid UTS mode: container....`

I get this error on multiple continers such as elasticsearch:5.4.3 and postgres

I am running the command

`circleci local execute build`

versions:

- CircleCi version:0.1.23845+f59d90e (release)
- Docker version 23.0.1, build a5ee5b1
- docker-compose version 1.29.2
- ubuntu 20.04

My config.yml file

```
version: 2

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: 722c/circle-ci-ubuntu-python-3:18.04-Node-10
        environment:
          - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.testing
          - DATABASE_URL=postgres://saleor:saleor@db/saleor
          - DJANGO_DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL=noreply@example.com
          - BOOK_SERVER_URL="test"
          - BOOK_SERVER_TOKEN="test"
      - image: postgres
        name: db
        environment:
          - POSTGRES_USER=saleor
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=saleor
      - image: elasticsearch:5.4.3
        name: search
        environment:
          - 'ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m'

    working_directory: /app

    steps:
      - checkout

      # Dependencies
      #   This would typically go in either a build or a build-and-test job when using workflows
      # Restore the dependency cache
      - restore_cache:            
      - run:
          name: Git submodules Sync
          command: git submodule sync

      - run:
          name: Git submodules update
          command: git submodule update --init

      - run:
          name: Install Python dependencies
          command: pip3 install -r requirements.txt

      - run:
          name: Install Node dependencies
          command: npm install

          # Save dependency cache
      - save_cache:
          key: v2-dep-{{ .Branch }}-{{ epoch }}
          paths:
            - ./node_modules
            - /root/.cache

      - run:
          name: Build the related files
          command: npm run build-emails && npm run build-assets --production

      - run:
          name: Run tests
          command: pytest
```

Is there something I am missing in the config.yml. I am still failry new with docker and circleci

What does the error mean exactly what is the UTS mode and how is it invalid.

I have checked that UTS namespace is enabled in on my kernal.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Same is happening in MAC M1 machine as well. 

Desktop Version 4.21.1 (114176)
Engine: 24.0.2

Comment: @FoyzulKarim  and Trax Bafley, did you find any solutions for this issues ?

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same issue and haven't been able to fix it. You might want to update your images to use circleci new images. for example cimg/postgres:15.2 then spin it again and see if it will make a difference.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34343701)